# как изменить размеры iframe через внешний js

Tags: javascript

Сделал свой виджет для сайтов. Но мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на него, он раскрывался полностью по высоте, как это к примеру сделано у виджетов онлайн косультантов. Что сейчас пробую:
подключаю внешний скрипт с кодом где создаю iframe(iframe.src опустил):

```
iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id = 'widget_stolik';
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    if(event.data == 'changeSize') {
        setTimeout(function() {
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        var iframe = document.getElementById('widget_stolik');
        var scrollHeight = Math.max(
          iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight,
          iframe.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight,
          iframe.contentWindow.document.body.clientHeight
        );

        if(height < scrollHeight) {
            iframe.style.height = height + 'px';
        }
        else {
            iframe.style.height = scrollHeight + 'px';
        }

    },100);
    }

});
```

И вызывая из скрипта в iframe:

```
parent.postMessage("changeSize", "*");
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://site.ru"
>   from accessing a cross-origin frame.

При попытке изменить размер iframe блока( как тогда делают разработчики виджетов? Может кто знает ответ?

Comment: Подключают js и добавляют div с чатом.

Comment: @Alex78191 , вот гляди, там iframe стоит http://www.jivochat.ru/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему меня не высоту самого iframe, а высоту внешнего блока. Как я понял браузер блокирует iframe.contentWindow ... т.е получить какие то параметры iframe нельзя, пришлось задавать цифры вручную. + Высоту iframe тоже нельзя изменить, но можно изменить высоту родительского блока. А iframe сделать height: 100%